# Merging an Option monad into IOEither?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, monads, fp-ts

I was trying to write a `localStorage` wrapper in [fp-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts) when I ran into a roadblock. I want to handle `null` values as well as exceptions thrown by `localStorage`, so I started with this code:

```js
import * as IOE from "fp-ts/IOEither";
import * as O from "fp-ts/Option";

const getItem = (key: string): IOE.IOEither<Error, O.Option<string>> =>
  IOE.tryCatch(
    () => O.fromNullable(localStorage.getItem(key)),
    E.toError
  )
```

The function above has a return signature of `IOEither<Error, Option<string>>`. I want to merge the `Option` into the `IOEither`, ie, get a `IOEither<Error, string>`. How would I achieve this?

P.S. I suppose the above problem is also relevant in the case of `TaskEither<Error, Option<string>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
import * as E from "fp-ts/Either";
import * as IOE from "fp-ts/IOEither";
import * as O from "fp-ts/Option";
import {pipe} from "fp-ts/function";

const getItem = (key: string): IOE.IOEither<Error, string> =>
  pipe(
    IOE.tryCatch(() => O.fromNullable(localStorage.getItem(key)), E.toError),
    IOE.chainEitherK(E.fromOption(() => new Error("key does not exist")))
  );
```

[`IOE.chainEitherK(f)`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/IOEither.ts.html#chaineitherk) is equivalent to `IO.map(E.chain(f))`:

```
export declare const chainEitherK:
  <E, A, B>(f: (a: A) => Either<E, B>) => (ma: IOEither<E, A>) => IOEither<E, B>
```

[`E.fromOption`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Either.ts.html#fromoption) converts an `Option<A>` into an `Either<E, A>` given a default error value if the option is `None`:

```
export declare const fromOption:
  <E>(onNone: Lazy<E>) => <A>(ma: Option<A>) => Either<E, A>
```